# Java loops and JOptionPane

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

Please Help....
I have been trying to figure this out for hours...

I have this program and I have to print out everything in the loop in the JoptionPane. But when the loop is done, the values are reset so how do I get to save all the totals and the put into the JOptionPane.
Here is the question:
PARTA Write an application called ProjectA.java

1. In the main
   a.  It will prompt the reviewer to enter a main course
   Example:
   Enter the luncheon main course: Burger, Hotdog, Pizza or Grilled Cheese
   b.  It will declare appropriate variables to store his data
   c.  It will create a Scanner object
2. write a  while loop controlled on  the amount entered being greater or equal to 0 (or not a -1)
3. then write a while loop to prompt the reviewer to enter all lunch costs as surveyed  separated by spaces, terminated with a -1
   Example:
   Enter all costs for the luncheon main dish Grilled Cheese  separated by spaces, terminate with a -1:
   1.95  2.55  0.99 -1
4. within the loop, add the amounts  to the accumulating total, increment the numItems counter  and read in the next amount using the scanner
5. when the loop ends , decrease  counter so that the -1 does not count as a lunch, calculate the average cost and output in a System.out.println statement the name, number of lunches surveyed, total money collected and the average cost of that lunch.  Do the same output in a JOptionPane – see sample execution below

PartB
Copy your ProjectA.java file into one named ProjectB.java 
Modify the code so that it prompts the reviewer to enter the maximum number of lunches in his survey using a JOptionPane
It will now need variables for a counter for the actual number of lunches and a maximum number of lunches

It will enclose the prompt for the luncheon main dish name and the while loop above in an outer loop controlled on the maximum number of lunches to be surveyed

When the inner loop ends, increment the number of lunches counter and reset the average, total and numItem  back to zero, then end the outer loop

Your intermediate output will look like the JOptionPane - so I have to print out all the info in the Joptionpane - and if they say to reset?  That is where I am stuck.

My program so far...

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import java.text.NumberFormat; 
    import java.util.Locale;


    public class LunchSurvey
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
         {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

         double averagecost = 0.0;
         double totalcollected = 0.0;
         double amount = 0.0;
         double burgersurvey = 0.0; 
         double burgertotal = 0.0;
         double burgeraverage = 0.0;
         int numofitems = 0;
         int maxlunch = 0;


         String lunchname = "";
         String lunchtotal = "";     

         lunchtotal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the maximum number of lunches in your survey");
         // lets say 3
         maxlunch = Integer.parseInt(lunchtotal);

    for (int j = 1; j <= maxlunch; j++)
    {

         // Getting the order
         lunchname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter lunch name:       Burger, Hotdog, Pizza or Grilled Cheese  ", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
         System.out.println("For " + lunchname + " enter all amounts collected separated by spaces and terminated with a -1" );
         // lets say the amounts are 1.00 1.00 2.00 -1

         while (amount >= 0)
          {
          totalcollected = totalcollected + amount;
          numofitems = numofitems + 1;
          amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
          }
        numofitems--;
        averagecost = totalcollected / numofitems;           

         System.out.println(lunchname + ":    Total surveyed: " + numofitems + "    Total collected: " + money.format(totalcollected) + "    Average Cost: " + money.format(averagecost));

         totalcollected = 0;
         numofitems = 0;
         amount = 0; 

    }
         /*Here is where I think that I am to print out all the lists same things like the println, all in one JOption pane. But if it clears all of the numbers to do another lunch number, then what is the secret to printing all of the lunch numbers in a JOptionPane?   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, lunchname????
         */
         }

    }
```

Comment: Use a map. Add in lunchnames as your key and cost as your value. Put values into the map as soon as user inputs options and costs for that  option. Once that is done, iterate over each entry in the map, calculate total cost and display everything at one go  !

Comment: You're setting `totalcollected`; `numofitems`; `amount` to zero AFTER the loop, but before you print them....not really sure what you expected

Comment: This is my first class in java,  and this is my homework for doing loops. I have not been taught yet about maps as I don't know what maps are.